# Why can I push from some tracking branches but not others?

Tags: git, git-push

Git on Windows 7 - git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0.

My company has multiple projects in Git repositories (on GitHub if that matters).

For some of them when I create a local tracking branch (e.g. `git push -u origin mybranch`, or `--set-upstream origin/mybranch`) I can pull and push to that branch with `git pull` & `git push` respectively and it all works fine.

But other in other cases (other projects), when I try the same scenario I can pull (`git pull`), but I have to specify origin and the branch when I push - e.g. `git push origin mybranch`. Just doing `git push` will return 'Everything up-to-date' even though it isn't and didn't push my desired changes up.

Below is the output from `git remote show origin` & `cat .git/config` for a repository where it works and one where it doesn't respectively.

I notice 2 things:

1. In the one that works p1_branch shows both push & pull entries in the remote show output. But for the one that doesn't, p2_branch only has a pull entry. But I don't know why that is. They were set up the same way.
2. One is set up to merge and the other to rebase. I have run `git config branch.master.rebase true` in the repository which doesn't work but not the other. I assume that explains this difference but don't understand if it could cause this problem.

Works (project1):

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:MyCompany/project1.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:MyCompany/project1.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master       tracked
    p1_branch    tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master       merges with remote master
    p1_branch    merges with remote p1_branch
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master       pushes to master  (up to date)
    p1_branch    pushes to p1_branch (up to date)

$ cat .git/config
[core]
        -- same for both repositories --
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@github.com:MyCompany/project1.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "p1_branch"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/p1_branch
```

Doesn't Work (project2):

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:MyCompany/project2.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:MyCompany/project2.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    -- cut a bunch of tracked branches entries --
    master       tracked
    ...
    p2_branch    tracked
    ...
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master     rebases onto remote master
    p2_branch  rebases onto remote p2_branch
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master     pushes to master (up to date)        

$ cat .git/config
[core]
        -- same for both repositories --
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@github.com:MyCompany/project2.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
        rebase = true
[submodule ...]
        -- cut a bunch of submodule stuff --
[merge]
        conflictstyle = diff3
[branch]
        autosetuprebase = always
[branch "p2_branch"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/p2_branch
        rebase = true
```

Comment: Sounds strange. Maybe you should play around with a local git repo (`git init`) and clone it into another directory to see whether you can reproduce this behaviour